# Is there a scale suitable for continuous tracking and recording of plant weight?

Tags: plant-physiology, lab-techniques

I want to measure water transpiration and evaporation in a bonsai tree, and measuring the weight of the tree in its pot is my proxy for water usage.  This has worked well with manual measurements, but I want to go to the next level.

I would like to monitor the weight of something continuously (e.g. once a minute) and access the data easily via a phone app.  Is there something like that?

There are numerous options for similar devices if you want to measure ambient temperature and humidity (e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/SensorPush-Wireless-Thermometer-Hygrometer-Android/dp/B01AEQ9X9I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AEQ9X9I)).

But all my searching for balances with similar functionality have failed.  I've found many lab balances and kitchen scales, and body weight scales.  Only the body weight scales interact with apps on your phone, but they do not record continuously.

If you know of one, or just have better google-fu than me and can suggest a more precise search term, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid this has absoultely nothing to do with biology... please take the [tour] and check out the [help] for details on what is on-topic here.  Thanks!

Comment: I’m also voting to close this question as it isn't about a biological mechanism or process.

Comment: Fair enough.  Moderators, feel free to delete, too.  I didn't because there is a penalty for deleting an answered question.

Comment: In my defense, I thought the application, trying to measure plant water use, was biology related, and this seems like a community that might use similar equipment to what I am looking for.  But if you think it is off-topic, I don't object.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this company  https://www.industrial-needs.com/scales-and-balances/recording-scales.htm

> Our scale software allows a real-time measurement on a computer and
> depending on the weighing data, they can also be saved with a date
> stamp as a TXT file on the computer